# JQuery UI Accordion not working correctly on my Drupal 6 site -- accordion not opening/closing

Tags: jquery, user-interface, drupal-6, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Using Drupal 6, and I believe I've correctly implemented jquery 1.3.2 and jquery ui 1.7.3

I'm so close, but my accordion is not executing correctly. It looks like not all the correct classes are being added by jquery ui/accordion to my accordion, and thus the "closed" parts of the accordion are actually staying open. Here's my page:

http://aaatoday.org/content/test-2012-aaa-annual-meeting-0

I've got this line in my template.php file:

```
jquery_ui_add('ui.accordion');
```

and this function call in a js file being loaded through my theme .info file:

```
Drupal.behaviors.nidaitnlBehavior = function (context) {
$("#accordion").accordion();
};
```

When using Firebug, I can see some of the accordion ui classes being added to the #accordion container div, and to the h3 headers, but not to the accordion divs themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have an answer, I'm very non codey, but... having just been looking into "accordion views" module, I've found it works very well, and would easily work perfectly for your page. It has a nice guide to how to alter the header (the clickable part of the accordion bar) to contain more than one field, and I've successfully entered html table formatting into the "rewrite the output of this field" area of the header field, so as to format it nicely. This could be divs. So you could either use this module to solve the issue, or maybe use it as a reference to fix your methods. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks... not really the answer I was looking for, but I did wind up going with Views Accordion anway -- just had to change the way I was thinking of things. Would still love to know why UI wasn't firing correctly, but ah well. It always feels more complex than its worth. Thanks for yoru input!